# С большим / с большими

Tags: окончания, существительные

Все пишут по-разному, но всё же как правильно?

*девушки с большим носом*

или

*девушки с большими носами*?

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически возможны оба варианта, но имеет значение контекст - могут быть стилистические предпочтения.

> Пластический хурург ведёт приём девушек с большим носом.

(здесь *абстракция*, условный диагноз; ср. "с насморком", "с ипотекой", "с высоким ростом")

> На опознание этой задержанной в качестве статисток подыскали девушек
>   с большими носами.

(у каждой свой неповторимый нос; аналогично "с богатыми бойфрендами" или "с модными телефонами")